# Syntax error for simplexml_load_file

Tags: php

I'm trying to append an item id from my database to an endpoint url within a `simplexml_load_file` function.

The function is called in the body section of an item page template that is part of a php mvc framework.

I've tried multiple different ways to fix the syntax error, and none seem to have worked.

Thanks in advance for your help.

> [E_PARSE][Code 4] syntax error, unexpected '<'

**My code:**

```
<?php   

//call our items xml file and store in object
$myItems = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.org/test/items.php?item_id=' . <?php echo $this->item['item_id']; ?>');

?>
```

Comment: Try to manually load the XML output and validate it here http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ , that should give you an idea to what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code to following:

```
<?php   

//call our items xml file and store in object
$myItems = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.org/test/items.php?item_id=' . $this->item['item_id']);

?>
```

you are not suppose to use `<?php` inside `<?php`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @mega6382. Did you also remove the semi-colon after the    ` $this->item['item_id'];` ? If so, could you explain why?

Comment: @ju1985oh Because thats the syntax of php. `;` represents end of a statement. But here a statement started from `$myItems = simplexml_load_file(` so it should end when the bracket closes `);`. adding a semi-colon before that will result in `syntax error`.

Comment: Very clear explanation for the removal of the semi-colon.